# SQL User Function (and performance): combining SELECT and IF in multiple RETURN statements

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The reason for my question is in part due to performance concerns. See note at end.

Is it possible to do something like this:

```sql
create function fn_x()
returns table
as
begin
if @Something1
    return select distinct y.val, x.* from x join y on x.a = y.a where y.val = @val
else if @Something2
    return select distinct z.val, x.* from x join z on x.a = z.a where z.val = @val
else
    return select @val val, x.* from x
end
```

The alternative would be something like this:

```sql
return
            select distinct y.val, x.* from x join y on x.a = y.a where @Something1 and y.val = @val
union all   select distinct z.val, x.* from x join z on x.a = z.a where @Something2 and z.val = @val
union all   select '' val, x.* from x where not @Something1 and not @Something2
```

or like this:

```sql
return
    select  @val val, x.*
    from    x
    where   (not @Something1 and not @Something2)
    or      (@Something1 and exists(select * from y where x.a = y.a and y.val = @val))
    or      (@Something2 and exists(select * from z where x.a = z.a and z.val = @val))
```

Assume "x" is a very large table used frequently. My concern is that the alternatives will slow my queries down.

(I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2)

**EDIT**: Why do I need a single function? The filter is based on external settings (perhaps not ideal but required). In short, the function is there to replace the table. Instead of using `select * from x` I must now use `select * from fn_x()`. Tables "y" and "z" represent permission tables, "@val" represents a user ID, and "@Something1" and "@Something2" represent external settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a will, there is a way :-)

```
create function fn_x()
returns @x table
(
    col1 int,
    col2 varchar(20)
)
as
begin
    -- declare @Something1 ...

    if @Something1
        insert @x select ...
    else if @Something2
        insert @x select ...
    else
        insert @x select ...
    return
end
go
```

A note on performance: from a quick call to `SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON` it seems that the original code bock 3 is better than block 2, but this above code is the best.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the alternatives because of syntax: you can have one return only with an in-line table valued function.

Personally, I'd say different JOINs means separate functions...

Comment: I need a single function due to external settings (I updated my post to explain). Any thoughts on performance?